# How to reset Tablesorter page size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination, tablesorter

I have tables that are dynamically loaded via AJAX. Every time a new table loads, I want to reset the page size to the default value. However, currently it is being set to the previously chosen drop-down value.

Currently, every time a new table is loaded I am doing the following:

```
    $(".pagesize").val(20);
    $("#data_table").tablesorter().tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager"), size:20});
```

However, the page size is being set to the last selected value. For e.g. with the options 20, 40, 80 and All, if I choose 80 for a table and then load a new table along with the above lines of codes, it is still being set to 80 instead of 20.

Does tablesorter store the previously used values? Why am I not able to reset the value.

I tried changing the value of dropdown in tablesorter pager example, and noticed that the selected option does not change in the select tag. 
In the attached image, I changed the page size from 10 to 20, however it did not change the selection option in the select tag as can be seen in the Google Dev Tool.

[image: Table Sorter Example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original version of tablesorter does not have methods in place to allow this... if you switch to my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), you can use the following command to set the page size.

```
$('table').trigger('pageSize', 15);
```

There is also a [`savePages` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#save-pages) (default set to `true`) which saves the user set page size.

Updating requires a minimal amount of option changes, if any, to make it work.

Comment: I had actually been using your fork of tablesorter plugin, but when this issue popped up, I was mistakenly looking through the original documentation. Thank you for pointing this out. Great job with the plugin!